# mysql+nosql (store some heavy text data in nosql)

Tags: mysql, nosql

I have mysql table for articles with fields:

```
*id
*user_id (int)
*article_text (text)
*status (int)
```

The table should have many rows in it. (~10 millions and may be much more)
I want to make it work faster. I have idea to store heavy text data in nosql, to remove data load from mysql server and use it only for indexing on small fields like user_id and status.

so I can do:

```
*id
*user_id (int)
*key_article_text (int)
*status (int)
```

and store huge text in nosql by key_article_text field value.

I see one problem with possible errors with integrity:

1. user send POST request with article data to store.
2. i create row in mysql with user_id, null key_article_text.
3. i wrote in in nosql.
4. i update null key_article_text

If error happend between 2,3 steps I will lose the text data and my row stay with null.
I can change the steps 2 and 3.

1. user send article to store.
2. i wrote in in nosql.
3. i wrote it in mysql.

But here on error between 2-3 steps. I can have unused keys in nosql.

How to avoid this kind of problems?

What pitfalls of this solution?